# Parsing Google Service Objects in PHP

Tags: php, google-cloud-platform, google-api, google-cloud-functions

I feel a bit silly, but I have no clue how to parse the objects that Google returns from their API in PHP, can someone shine a light on it?

So for instance, if I request:

```
print_r($job->getState());
```

I get this:

```
Google\Cloud\Scheduler\V1\HttpTarget Object
(
    [uri:Google\Cloud\Scheduler\V1\HttpTarget:private] => http://example.com/cron-check.php
    [http_method:Google\Cloud\Scheduler\V1\HttpTarget:private] => 1
    [headers:Google\Cloud\Scheduler\V1\HttpTarget:private] => Google\Protobuf\Internal\MapField Object...
```

So how in the world do I get the uri value out of this object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Googling the Object you're receiving in response, I found the source code for it:

https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-php/blob/master/Scheduler/src/V1/HttpTarget.php

Looking at this, there appears to be a simple getter method for the URI property. Try:

```
$job->getState()->getUri();
```

Comment: Thanks Greg. That surely did the trick. I guess I should have looked through the source code. I just assumed there's a universal way to parse these objects. Thanks so much. I really do appreciate your response.

Comment: Not a problem :-)

Comment: You can also use `json_decode($job->serializeToJsonString(), true)` to get the value as an array.

Comment: Yes, jdp! That's exactly what I was looking for. You rock!